# Change certificate in Primary Keystore of WSO2 servers

Tags: wso2

We have been using WSO2 (IS v.5.3, ESB v.5.0.0, API-M v.1.10, DSS v.3.5.1) servers for about three years. We installed only one and the same certificate for all servers. All servers are working in the same VM. Certificate was installed in Primary Keystore configured in carbon.xml . Now it's about to expire so we have to change our certificate,  that's why I have some questions:

- Since Primary Keystore is used for Data encryption and decryption,
  will I have problems after changing certificate in Primary Keystore?
- Could I now use 2 keystores, one with self-signed certificate for
  Data encryption and decryption and configured in carbon.xml and
  another with CA trusted certificate SSL keystore which is used for
  tomcat transport (with 9443 connector). It is configured in
  /repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml?
- I found in one article
  (http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/09/01/configure-keystore-jks-files-in-wso2-products/)
  that "..Validity period of the Primary KeyStore certificate does not 
  matter for the encrypt/decrypt the data...". So, maybe I can use old 
  expired certificate in Primary Keystore and install new one in SSL
  keystore configured in /repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have installed new certificates: one, self-signed, for encryption/decryption and one CA trusted for SSL connections. I only had to renew data-sources in servers DB. I had to set value *false* for attribute *encrypted* and write plain-text password. Attribute *encrypted* is in *password* tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer the wso2 official documentation on Keystore configuration to find answers for all the questions :) https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products That explains how you can configure the keystore

Comment: Yes, I have red this documentation. But only one question: if I renew certificate in Primary Keystore will I have problems?

Comment: Maybe you could answer one more question: 
Could I leave old, expired certificate for encryption/decryption and add new SSL certificate for communication purposes? This is just not for long. In the near future, we intend to upgrade our servers and we will use certificates based on your recommendations